# How can I add a dashed border to any shape?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

What methods are there to accomplish this effect?

Comment: Do you need the image to be Raster or vector?

Comment: @lawndartcatcher the tag says Photoshop :)

Comment: Whoops. Sorry. Haven't had coffee yet.

Comment: Hehe, no worries :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two ways to do this, but they aren't perfect. I am certain there are other methods as well.

1) create a path, pick a rectangular brush (or make your own), set a brush tip spacing of more than 100%, and then apply a stroke to the path using the selected brush

or

2) create a small checkerboard pattern the size you want it, make a black shape on a layer, set the layer blending option "stroke" to "pattern" and specify your pattern. Set the "color" option to white. If you want to overlay this onto something, set the layer blend mode to "darken" and the white will be transparent, or make a layer mask that will knock out the shape.

I'll bounce back with some links to help accomplish this: I don't have time right now.

Answer (score 0):

I checked how to do that long a go and every research lead to doing it in illustrator and then importing it to photoshop.

which is just adding a normal stroke and it gives you the dashed option

I don't normally use illustrator so can't give specific instructions but is easy

- i hope it can be done in photoshop

Comment: This isn't really much an answer as it is a suggestion. I feel it should have been a comment.

Comment: i swear i agree, i just remembered after writing it, sorry